# CUDAFY emulator?

Tags: cuda, emulation, cudafy.net

Is there an emulator for Cudafy?
I have looked into Ocelot but I am not sure if Cudafy codes can be compiled on it.
If anyone has any suggestions for an alternative emulator, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Cudafy, I haven't used Ocelot. But Ocelot itself works with visual studio. There shouldn't be any problems running Cudafy with Ocelot just as long as Cudafy is compatible with Visual Studio 10.

There are these two emulators that I came across.

Barra:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/408577/barra-a-gpu-simulator-to-run-cuda-apps/

Waste:
http://codinggorilla.domemtech.com/?p=553

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.